# Java create LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

i want to create LinkedHashMap in which will be another LinkedHashMap like this:

```
Array
(
    [width] => 450
    [height] => 450
    [file] => D:/images/bolivia-gonzales1.jpg
    [sizes] => Array
        (

                    [medium] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )

                    [twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )
```

My code is:

```
LinkedHashMap imagesArray = new LinkedHashMap();
imagesArray.put("width", image.getWidth());
            imagesArray.put("height", image.getHeight());
            imagesArray.put("file", destinationFile);

Set arrayList = new HashSet();

LinkedHashMap thumbnail = new LinkedHashMap();
            thumbnail.put("file", newUrl150);
            thumbnail.put("width", image.getWidth());
            thumbnail.put("height", image.getHeight());
            thumbnail.put("mime-type", "image/jpeg");

            LinkedHashMap thumbnailMap = new LinkedHashMap();
            thumbnailMap.put("thumbnail", thumbnail);

            arrayList.add(thumbnailMap);

LinkedHashMap medium = new LinkedHashMap();
            medium.put("file", newUrl300);
            medium.put("width", out.getWidth());
            medium.put("height", out.getHeight());
            medium.put("mime-type", "image/jpeg");

            LinkedHashMap mediumMap = new LinkedHashMap();
            mediumMap.put("medium", medium);

            arrayList.add(mediumMap);

imagesArray.put("sizes", arrayList);
```

And i get this array:

```
 Array
(
    [width] => 450
    [height] => 450
    [file] => D:/images/bolivia-gonzales1.jpg
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [medium] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar] => Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )

                )
```

As you can see in "size" there are Arrays with key [0], [1].

How to build LnkedHashMap, that won't have the [0], [1] keys?

I was trying with different Lists, Maps, Sets but unfortunatelly all give me output with "Key"

Comment: What do you mean by *How to build LnkedHashMap, that won't have the [0], [1] keys?*. A map is a <key, value> paired collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking about creating a Map inside another Map, but you are putting a Set inside the imagesArray Map. Just use map inside that as well, and you can define the key when you are putting one inside of the other.